# Can we get current country of device dynamically from locale.?

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, android-locale

I am developing wearable applications (for smartwatches), and want to access the device's current country to show distance unit(km/mile) based on locale..
I am able to get the device country from `Locale.getDefault().country` but once I update the local with a specific language and then later try to access the device country then it returns a blank value.
I can not use `TelephonyManager` since watches/tabs don't have sim cards.

Below is the small code snippett,

`val locale = Locale(language, Locale.getDefault().country)`
`Locale.setDefault(locale)`
`val configuration: Configuration = context.resources.configuration configuration.setLocale(locale) configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)`

`Logger.info("Locale Country :${locale.country}")`

`Logger.info("Confi. Locale Country:${context.resources.configuration.locales[0].country}")`

I get blank in logs.

I can save the device country before updating the local and user whenever required but if a user installs the app in India and flies to Australia still then it will still return country as India.
Please guide. Thanks in advance.